# How should I use % sign that it can be printed out correctly?

Tags: symbols

when I try to write 90% I do 90 $%$ , but none works and anything after the % doesn't print in the output, any solution ?

Comment: `\%` is how it is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to use `\%`, the preferred way `\SI{5}{\percent}`, for example. The `siunitx` package approach has a 'better' spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

One way: 5\% 

or \SI{5}{\percent}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much , I couldn't find the similar questions by my keywords

Comment: @Farzad64: Well, admittedly, looking for `%` as `Escape character` is not very straightforward, right